# How to iterate discontinuous range in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim rData As Range
rData = Range("Sheet1!$D$4,Sheet1!$A$6:$A$8,Sheet1!$B$4,Sheet1!$C$8")
```

How can I iterate through values in all cells of `rData`?

Comment: `RangeObject.Areas`

Comment: `For Each rCell In rData`...`Next rCell`. Declare `rCell` as a `Range`.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Both `For Each rCell In rData...Next rCell` and `For Each rCell In rData...Next` works. What is the difference?

Comment: I don't think there is a difference. `Next rCell` just makes it clear where the loop ends - easier to read if using nested loops.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with *"three cells of `rData`"*?. You range holds more cells, do you mean the `Range.Area(1)` meaning `Sheet1!$A$6:$A$8` in this case. So to avoid confusion here: Your full discontinuous range object holds **four Areas**, and only the second area holds **three cells**.

Comment: Sorry question was edited later and forgot to change three to all. Anyway @DarrenBartrup-Cook 's solution worked.

Comment: `Next varName` is useful when you are dealing with multiple, or nested arrays or ranges; it makes the code more readable, but also enforces the current `For` loop - useful for when you (ahem!) use a `GoTo` or some other form of execution flow.  Note that if you do not use `Next varName` in nested `For` loops, and jump outside of your inner for loop interesting and unpredictable things can happen. Code smell-wise, you should always be careful about employing nested `For` loops, but it's not wrong in every case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this code

```
Sub a()
    Dim rData As Range, cell as Range
    Set rData = Sheet1.Range("D4, A6:A8, B4,C8")
    For Each cell In rData
        MsgBox cell
    Next
End Sub
```